# FWER, FDR and multiple comparisons for Beginners

Tags: multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate, familywise-error

Wikipedia:

"In statistics, family-wise error rate (FWER) is the probability of making one or more false discoveries, or type I errors, among all the hypotheses when performing multiple hypotheses tests."

"The false discovery rate (FDR) is one way of conceptualizing the rate of type I errors in null hypothesis testing when conducting multiple comparisons."

I don't understand the difference between these two concepts. How do they not mean the same?

Perhaps you can help me by further elaborating the following example:

Say the probability for an unbiased coin to substantially deviate from a 50/50 head/tail-distribution in a sequence of 1,000 tosses is 0.001.

If I want to find out if one coin is biased I throw it 1,000 times and if it shows heads ~500 times I can be quite sure it is not biased.

However if I throw a million coins 1,000 times and deem those biased who don't show a 50/50-distribution of heads and tails, I *will* categorize unbiased coins as biased, because the probability of an unbiased coin showing deviating from the 50/50-distribution is multiplied by the number of coins (1 million).

Thus from a set of one million unbiased coins, I have to expect about 1,000,000*0.001=1,000 coins to deviate substantially from the 50% tails, 50% heads-distribution.

As far as I understood this is multiple hypotheses testing (synonymous: multiple comparisons?) as I am testing the hypothesis "coin is unbiased" a million times, and the false discovery rate FDR is 1,000 in this example.

But what, then, is the FWER (family wise error rate)?

Comment: Does this help? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59681/why-is-controlling-fdr-less-stringent-than-controlling-fwer?rq=1

Comment: See the fdr section in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166323/misunderstanding-a-p-value/166327#166327

Comment: @ChristophHanck what does $m_0$ (or $m$ for that matter) stand for? (I'm referring to your link)

Comment: The number of true hypotheses.

Comment: @ChristophHanck so $m$ is the number of all hypotheses?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @ChristophHanck don't you mean that $m_0$ is the number of true null hypotheses?

Comment: That's what I'm saying, yes, I should have added true.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the reason you're confused may be that you are considering the special case that all null hypotheses are true (i.e. *m* = *m0*). When all null hypotheses are true, the FWER and FDR are indeed the same. For *m* independent tests of true null hypotheses, FDR = FWER = 1-(1-alpha)^*m*.

The difference comes when some null hypotheses are true and some null hypotheses are false. In that case, the FDR tells you the expected proportion of *significant* tests (not of *all* tests) that will be Type I errors. Computing the FDR is then not as simple, because it depends on the proportion of null hypotheses that are false and also on *power* (the probabilities of significance for the tests of the false null hypotheses).

Neither FWER nor FDR can ever be greater than 1. The value of 1,000 that you computed is a different error rate called the per-family error rate: PFER = alpha*m.