# FDR correction stronger than Bonferroni?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, bonferroni, false-discovery-rate

Is it possible to get a situation where, in a multiple-testing scenario, for some individual tests, the [Benjamini&Yukatieli (2001)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-29/issue-4/The-control-of-the-false-discovery-rate-in-multiple-testing/10.1214/aos/1013699998.full)-correction ends up being more stringent than Bonferroni? I.e. that for some tests,
$$
p_{\text{Bonferroni}} < p_{BY}
$$

I seem to have encountered this with data and while I have no conceptual problem with it (the procedures are after all quite different), but would have intuitively said that with every correction any p-value can be at most as large as with Bonferroni.

Comment: related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59681/why-is-controlling-fdr-less-stringent-than-controlling-fwer/143852#143852

Comment: @ChristophHanck The statement that any control of FWER will trivially also control FDR would also support the idea that any FDR-corrected p-value will be at most as large as its FWER-corrected cousin. But again, it doesn't offer a direct proof that the reverse can't occur for singular tests in a multiple testing situation

Comment: OK, this might be more relevant then: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238458/whats-the-formula-for-the-benjamini-hochberg-adjusted-p-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that indeed, this can and does trivially happen, as tested on two different implementations in Python, from [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) and [pingouin](https://doi.org/10.21105/joss.01026), with only two tests and p-values of 0.01 and 0.1.

```
from pingouin import multicomp as pingouin_multicomp
from statsmodels.stats.multitest import multipletests as statsmodels_multicomp
pvals = [0.01, 0.1]
```

With this,

```
pingouin_multicomp(pvals, method="bonf")[1] -> array([0.02, 0.2 ])
pingouin_multicomp(pvals, method="fdr_by")[1] -> array([0.03, 0.15])
statsmodels_multicomp(pvals, method="fdr_by")[1] -> array([0.03, 0.15])
```

Unless there is some deep conceptual mistake I made, it would appear that the smaller value gets corrected more.

Interestingly, this does not seem to happen with the original [Benjamini & Hochberg (1995)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2346101) procedure (as suggested by the method outlined in the post linked by Christoph Hanck). If anyone wants to outline the difference, I'll shift the accept; for now this is at least what seems to be confirmation that I'm not crazy.